# Pushing a new url whose only change with the previous url is a query parameter

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm trying to redirect the user from a page to the same page with the query parameter `buy=true` after the user has logged in. After the user has logged in, in my service response handler, I was trying to use the push function in `react-router-redux` to push the state. This did not work. Neither did the `replace` function. The new URL got updated, but my components were not rendered again. What is the right way to this?

This is what I tried

```
dispatch(push(/home?buy=true))
dispatch(replace(/home?buy=true))
browserHistory.push(/home?buy=true)
```

Comment: How exactly did you try using `push` and `replace` finding it didn't work? Please mention in detail what you have tried already. Just saying the name of functions doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try an approach like that:

- Create a local state to make the elements you want re-render
- Inside *ComponentWillReceiveProps* or *ComponentDidUpdate*, you should trigget a *setState* changing your current state

Something like that:

```
constructor() {

this.state = {
  hasRefreshed: false
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   const paramsHaveChanged = nextProps.location.query !== this.props.location.query
   if (paramsHaveChanged) {
     this.setState({ hasRefreshed: true })
   }
   if (this.state.hasRefreshed) {
     this.setState({ hasFrefreshed: false })
   }
}

render() {

  if (hasRefreshed) return null
  return() {
    //other elements
  }
}
```